# Accidentally overriding properties

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller with the following properties:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   isSomething: false,
   notSomething: Ember.computed.not('isSomething')
}
```

And for some reason when I look at the controller in the debugger I have `isSomething` defined in the "Own Properties" section but then also as a property in "App.MyController". In the "App.MyController" the debugger claims that `isSomething` is "overridden by it's own properties" which I guess it is but how did I get into this state?

On a side note, the `notSomething` computed property starts as *false* and does not change when I change the value of `isSomething` in "own properties" (I can't change it in "App.MyController" section).

**UPDATE**

Ok, it seems to have more complexity than just the code above. I'm still pretty in the dark but here's what I can tell ...

1. The `MyController` is an array controller where each row is displaying a View which has a conditional in the template referencing the `notSomething` property.
2. If the conditional statement is stated as `{{#if notSomething}}` then the above-mentioned overriding of properties doesn't happen but I think that's because it is looking in the view for the property ... indeed changing the value of the `notSomething` variable in the controller has no effect.
3. If the conditional statement is stated as `{{#if controller.notSomething}}` then the above mentioned *does* take effect.

Hopefully that helps a bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 2**

There was some confusion about what I meant by looking at the controller in debugger. Here's a screenshot that hopefully clarifies:

[image]

Please note the actual class name is UomsController (not `MyController`) but code snippets are a direct representation.

Comment: What do you mean by "I look at the controller in the debugger"? I suspect that you may be irritated by the fact that App.MyController is the class of your controller. It is not the actual instance.

Comment: I've added a screen shot of what I mean. Ignore the name variations that I made in my example in effort to protect the innocent. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you see here is the following. When you call `Ember.ArrayController.extend` you are passing a hash to it containing the default values. You can see these values in the debugger under App.UomsController/App.MyController. **There you see the default values/ the template for instances of your class.** In the section `Own properties` you see the actual values of the instance of your class. So after a property is set on the controller you see the actual value there. So this looks fine to me and you don't have to worry :-)

**TL;DR**
The section "Own properties" shows the values of the instance of your class, while the section named like your Controller shows the default values you passed to the `extend` method.